# Vuejs and Stripe Checkout : error message `did you register the component correctly?`

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to work with the `vue-stripe-checkout` plugin. I declared my import and Vue.use() in the main.js file :
`import VueStripeCheckout from "vue-stripe-checkout";`
`Vue.use(VueStripeCheckout, 'pk_test_MYTESTPK');`

Then I'm simply trying to use it in my code as suggested in the plugin documentation : `<vue-stripe-checkout [...]></vue-stripe-checkout>`

But I've got an error saying :
`Unknown custom element: <vue-stripe-checkout> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

After looking for hours, i've no idea why this doesn't work.

Does someone have an idea ?

Here is an extrait from my main.js file :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
[...MY IMPORTS...]
import VueStripeCheckout from "vue-stripe-checkout";


// global components
import GlobalComponents from './globalComponents'

// app.vue
import App from './App'


[... OTHER IMPORTS AND ROUTER OPERATIONS...]

Vue.use(InstantSearch);
[... MY Vue.use() ...]
Vue.use(VueStripeCheckout, 'pk_test_MYTESTPK');


new Vue({
    store,
    i18n,
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
    components: { App }
}).$mount('#app')
```

And how I'm trying to use it, in a *.vue component (this is only the exemple provided by git) :

````
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-stripe-checkout
      ref="checkoutRef"
      :image="image"
      :name="name"
      :description="description"
      :currency="currency"
      :amount="amount"
      :allow-remember-me="false"
      @done="done"
      @opened="opened"
      @closed="closed"
      @canceled="canceled"
    ></vue-stripe-checkout>
    <button @click="checkout">Checkout</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      image: 'https://i.imgur.com/HhqxVCW.jpg',
      name: 'Shut up and take my money!',
      description: 'Cats are the best dog!',
      currency: 'PHP',
      amount: 99999
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async checkout () {
      // token - is the token object
      // args - is an object containing the billing and shipping address if enabled
      const { token, args } = await this.$refs.checkoutRef.open();
    },
    done ({token, args}) {
      // token - is the token object
      // args - is an object containing the billing and shipping address if enabled
      // do stuff...
    },
    opened () {
      // do stuff 
    },
    closed () {
      // do stuff 
    },
    canceled () {
      // do stuff 
    }
  }
}
</script>```



Thanks !
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the tag `vue-stripe-checkout` in your component, you must import it first.
You can import a component globally OR within another component.

Doing this should import the Stripe component in your container component:

```
<script>
import VueStripeCheckout from "vue-stripe-checkout";
  ...
export default {
  ...
  components: {
     'vue-stripe-checkout': VueStripeCheckout,
  },
  ...
}
</script>
```

If you need more info on component registration: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: Thanks. I was willing to import it globally. According to the doc here : https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-stripe-checkout you don't need to import it at the composant level (and according the the github threads on the project, it fails when doing it)